# How do I install separate programs on Windows XP profiles?

Tags: installation, user-accounts, user-profiles

I would like to Install Microsoft SQL Server Express and Oracle Databse Express on a single Windows XP Home SP3 computer for 2 different users separately.

What I want is User1 has only MSSQL Server Express installed, User2 has only Oracle Express installed.

What is the best (easiest) way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *easy* way to achieve this. I can not talk for Oracle (however I would assume the same), but SQL gets installed as a service and is available for everyone on the machine.

If users are administrators, there is no real way to prevent them from accessing each one, even then, unless the database is secured (encrypted, usernames, passwords etc.) it is possible they can just take a backup of all data.

If they are just users, I would recommend that you install as normal under an administration account, then you could put both services to manual startup and run a logon script for each user that just has "net start sqlexpress" etc, or along these lines.

You may be able to go further by starting the services under the account name of that user and using NTFS permission on the program folders so each user cannot access the other database and will not have permission to start the database.

I know SQL is compatible with this - I do something similar on a domain, however I have never run it as a limited user. Again, I can not talk or give advice with Oracle, but I would assume it was similar.

Answer (score 1):

As Wil said, it's not easy. Really speaking, I think at least for SQL, it is not possible. All you can do is remove The "BUILTIN\Administartors" & users from the people who have right on the master, & just keep 'sa' & the user whom you want SQL to be accessible. That way, the databases will only be accessible to your user.